# How to use native xib in phone gap?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, phonegap-plugins

i am using phone gap for an application in xcode.Now i want to create one native xib inside the same project.i will write appropriate code in objective-c.Now my doubt is .how to use/connect the xib into view that i have created in phone gap.Is there any plug in to do this.Help me .thanks in advance.

Comment: the reason to develop using Phone Gap is you need a hybrid application to work with multi-platforms . How come you want to make a native xib . instead of this why you didn't make it all native iOS ?...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a plugin or find an existing plugin that fits your needs.

[PhoneGap Documentation on iOS plugin development](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS)